# React Native Animated how to implement ReLU (y = 0 for negative x, y = x for positive x)

Tags: react-native, animation, symbolic-math, declarative, react-animated

I'm trying to bind a (native) animation on React Native based on scroll offset animated value of a scroll view. What I basically want to achieve is the ReLU function, that is:

```
f(x) = 0 if x < 0
f(x) = x if x >= 0
```

[image]

I've tried `Animated.multiply` to get the square and divide by itself again to get the sign but that doesn't seem to work either.

How can I achieve that function using the declarative `Animated` API (so no conditionals/ifs or any imperative code) to bind to some animated property?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved the issue using clamping/interpolation. Basically I've set input/output range to be a large negative number to zero, and I've set the extrapolation to clamp:

```
const ty = this.props.boundOffset.interpolate({
    inputRange: [-1000,0],
    outputRange: [-1000, 0],
    extrapolate: 'clamp',

})
```

It worked perfectly.